# Clicking in selected text in Sublime Text 3 does not deselect text

Tags: sublimetext3

I must have accidentally set some option or something, but I can't figure out what I did.

Previously when I would select text in Sublime Text 3, I could click anywhere in the selected text and it would deselect and I'd go on with what I'm doing.

Today when I click somewhere in the selected text block to start editing or something, nothing happens. Instead I'm forced to click outside of the selected text to deselect it.

Does anyone know what I might have accidently done to create this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely culprit is `"drag_text"`. Open **`Preferences → Settings`** and in your user settings on the right, add the following line:

```js
"drag_text": false,
```

This will override any global settings, but not any personal language-specific settings or project settings, so make sure to check them too.